# How to properly annotate lengths for a polygon(trapezium). How to calculate the perpendicular height?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I would like to know how to annotate a trapezoid.  I think I have the widths okay but I'm having trouble calculating the height. I have adapted the code from answer to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178582/how-to-annotate-the-following-trapezoid-picture)  Once I have the height, I think I can make a dashed line to show it's perpendicular.  Something like this.

[image]

**Code:**

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}%to allow for \text{} command in math
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mysidea}{7}
\newcommand{\mysideb}{4}
\newcommand{\Height}{3}
\newcommand{\thisheight}{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[trapezium,
    draw = black,
    text = black,
    fill = cyan!20,
    minimum width = 4cm,
    minimum height=2cm,
    trapezium left angle = 120,
    trapezium right angle = 80] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \draw[red,|-|] ([yshift=3mm]a.top left corner)--node[midway, fill=white,text=black]{$\mysidea$ cm}([yshift=3mm]a.top right corner); 
 \draw[red,|-|] ([yshift=-3mm]a.bottom left corner)--node[midway,fill=white, text=black]{$\mysideb$ cm}([yshift=-3mm]a.bottom right corner); 
 %%%%%need help with the calculation of the correct height
  \draw[red,|-|] ([xshift=3mm]a.bottom right corner)--node[midway,fill=white, text=black,xshift=4mm]{$\Height$ cm}([xshift=3mm]$(a.bottom right corner)+(90:\thisheight)$); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I annotate the perpendicular height even if the angle changes?

Comment: seems to be okay -- what exactly is the problem

Comment: When the angle is different, I have to guess the height.  I would like it to be calculated somehow.

Comment: this answer should solve the requirement -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286571/197451

Comment: \draw[|-|, dashed, red] (a.bottom right corner) -- (a.bottom right corner|-a.north) node[midway, right] {3.5 cm};  adapted from the code suggested by js bibra tex.stackexchange.com/a/286571/197451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is to find the correct end point for the annotation, you can use an auxiliar coordinate and the perpendicular coordinate system.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}%to allow for \text{} command in math
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mysidea}{7}
\newcommand{\mysideb}{4}
\newcommand{\Height}{3}
\newcommand{\thisheight}{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[trapezium,
    draw = black,
    text = black,
    fill = cyan!20,
    minimum width = 4cm,
    minimum height=2cm,
    trapezium left angle = 120,
    trapezium right angle = 80] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \draw[red,|-|] ([yshift=3mm]a.top left corner)--node[midway, fill=white,text=black]{$\mysidea$ cm}([yshift=3mm]a.top right corner); 
 \draw[red,|-|] ([yshift=-3mm]a.bottom left corner)--node[midway,fill=white, text=black]{$\mysideb$ cm}([yshift=-3mm]a.bottom right corner); 
 %%%%%need help with the calculation of the correct height
  \draw[red,|-|] ([xshift=3mm]a.bottom right corner) coordinate(aux) --node[midway,fill=white, text=black,xshift=4mm]{$\Height$ cm}(aux|-a.north); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]